# external xml file integration in android

Tags: android

i am developing one application for displaying images and labels and its sound.i want to get this info from xml .where i need to keep xml file in android project how to get values from that xml file

Thanks in advance

Aswan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can package the xml file in `assets/` directory inside your apk. With that, you can use

```
AssetManager assets = context.getAssets();
InputStream in = assets.open("myfile.xml");
```

If your file just contains labels, or strings, you can save it in put it in  `res/values/strings.xml` inside your apk. In this case you can access the string values using the android generated `R` class

If you have a custom file (with custom structure) you can use DOM, SAX, or Xml Pull to read those files. e.g.

```
DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = builder.parse(in);
```